# Postgres: Sequelize Group, isn't working when referencing the include table column

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

This is my code,
I really don't know how to fix this issue anymore

when I enter this code.

```
     db.models.Price.findAll({
        attributes:['id', 'item.item_name'],
        group: [
            ['masterfile_price.id','item.id','item.item_name']
        ],
        // [sequelize.literal('Item.item_name')]
        //  ['masterfile_price.id']

        raw: true,
        include: [{
            model: db.models.Item,
            as: 'item',
            attributes: ['id',"item_name"],
        }],

    })
```

It will give me this error
error DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: column "item.item_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
I don't know why

the query is this

```
SELECT
"masterfile_price"."id",
"item"."item_name",
"item"."id" AS "item.id",
"item"."item_name" AS "item.item_name" 
FROM
"masterfile_prices" AS "masterfile_price"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "masterfile_items" AS "item" ON "masterfile_price"."itemId" = "item"."id" 
GROUP BY
"masterfile_price"."id";
```

the problem is
I only want the item_name

in my orignal query without using sequelize
it's working this

```
    SELECT
    "item"."item_name" AS "item.item_name" 
    FROM
    "masterfile_prices" AS "masterfile_price"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "masterfile_items" AS "item" ON "masterfile_price"."itemId" = "item"."id" 
    GROUP BY
    item.item_name;
```

which will the results of

| item.item_name |
| --- |
| test9 |
| test10 |

I don't know why I can't replicate it, in sequelize,
or am I missing something?

or is there something wrong with sequelize group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group` option should be either `string | Fn | Col` or an array of `string | Fn | Col`. So you need to remove extra brackets:

```js
group: ['masterfile_price.id','item.id','item.item_name']
```

If you want to select and group by only `item.item_name` then you need to indicate only it in both `attributes` and `group` options:

```js
db.models.Price.findAll({
        attributes:[[Sequelize.col('item.item_name'), 'item_name']],
        group: Sequelize.col('item.item_name'),
        raw: true,
        include: [{
            model: db.models.Item,
            as: 'item',
            attributes: [],
        }],
    })
```

Comment: I see, so it shouldn't be an array of array,
that's why it isn't working,

thank you very much :)